# Handle ill formed XML in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

have to handle a bunch of XML files which are ill formed.
They are ill formed in the way that in many childs a attribute name has a white Space:

```
<...>
    <bar attr1="..." attr xy="..."> 
        foo
    </bar>
</...>
```

Is there a propber way to handle this?
At the moment I am using Python ElementTree for Parsing.

(I guess the whitespace is the problem, the error message points to the whitespace.

```
cElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 435, column 214
```

as far as I understand it is interpreted as to attributes where one misses the value)

I am aware of the possibility to just replace the wrong stuff beore parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use beautiful soup, or lxml with the beautiful soup backend. Note, however, that beautiful soup is likely to parse "attribute name" with a space in it as two attributes.

An alternative would be to use regular expressions to fix up your input first.